# What is 'an identification map'?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, fiber-bundles

From Husemöller's 'Fiber Bundles' (slightly rephrased):

**Proposition:** Consider a bundle $\xi: E \to B$, and a mapping $f: B' \to B$. Then for any $s \in \Gamma(\xi)$ there is a $\sigma: B' \to E \times_B B'$ defined by $\sigma(b') = (b', sf(b'))$ that is a section of $f^*(\xi)$, and $f_\xi \sigma = s f$. If $f$ is an identification map and if $\sigma \in \Gamma(f^*(\xi))$ is such that $f_\xi \sigma$ is constant on $f^{-1}(b)$ for all $b \in B$, then there is a $s \in \Gamma(\xi)$ such that $sf = f_\xi \sigma$.

*Proof:* [...] For the second statement, we have a factorization of $f_\xi \sigma$ by $f$, giving a map $s: B \to E$ with $sf = f_\xi \sigma$. Moreover, $\xi sf = \xi f_\xi \sigma = f f^*(\xi) \sigma = f$ and $\xi s = 1_B$, since $f$ is surjective. Then $s$ is the desired cross section.

---

*What does 'an identification mapping' mean?* Does it merely mean a surjection? I'm sure it can't mean a homeomorphism or even a bijection because that would make the second part trivial.

Comment: It's also called a quotient map. It means the map is surjective and the codomain carries the quotient topology induced by the relation $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given two topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an identification map iff it is surjective and for every subset $U$ of $Y$, $U\in\tau_Y$ is equivalent to $f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_X$.

Comment: This means that an identification map is always continuous right?

Comment: @Peter Yes, because, in particular, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all open subsets $U$ of $Y$.

Comment: I'm starting to learn about quotient spaces and I can't see clearly why do we need f to be surjective

Comment: @IñakiMendieta The idea of quotient space is to identify points, through an equivalence relation, to obtain a new space. If the map would not be surjective would mean that after identifying points you would get extra points out of nowhere. The latter is not the desired effect of identifying points together, i.e., of 'quotienting' the original space.

Answer (score 3):

As Iasafro says, this means that $B$ has the [quotient topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space) induced by the surjection $f\colon B' \to B$ and the topology on $B'$. The implication of this that Husemöller is using is that any continuous map $g\colon B' \to C$ that is constant on the fibres of $f$ will induce a unique continuous map $g_*\colon B \to C$ such that $g_* \circ f = g$.

[The existence and uniqueness of such a map of *sets* is trivial. To see that it's continuous, let $U$ be an open subset of $C$. Then $f^{-1}(g_*^{-1}(U)) = g^{-1}(U)$ is open as $g$ is continuous, and hence $g_*^{-1}(U)$ is open because $B$ has the quotient topology induced by $f$.]